# Stacking Manual of Quickness of Action +

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Can I stack the bonus of two or more [Manual of Quickness of Action +5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#manualofQuicknessofAction)?

I didn't find nothing saying that it's not okay, but it's kind of overpower this item if you can stack and have tons of money...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No - Bonuses of the same type don't stack**

No, you can't. The book gives an "inherent bonus of +1 to +5". Reading a second one gives you another inherent bonus. Inherent is the type of bonus. [Two bonuses of the same type don't stack, you use the largest one](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm):

> In most cases, modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a
>   cumulative effect) if they come from different sources and have
>   different types (or no type at all), but do not stack if they have the
>   same type or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast
>   twice in succession). If the modifiers to a particular roll do not
>   stack, only the best bonus and worst penalty applies. Dodge bonuses
>   and circumstance bonuses however, do stack with one another unless
>   otherwise specified.

So if you read a +1 Manual of Quickness ,and then read a +4 Manual of Quickness, your bonus is +4 (the larger one). If you read two Manual of Quickness +5, your bonus is +5 and you wasted a lot of money.

That bonus *does* stack with Gloves of Dexterity (enhancement bonus), and other bonuses with different or no type.

You could also read a different tome, like the Manual of Bodily Health, to increase another stat. As those aren't affecting the same stat (the second tome is for Constitution), that works fine.

Comment: Thanks clear my mind. Now I don't need to spend tons of money to get more bonus.

Comment: Note that if you manage to find a _Manual of the Winding Way_ (Dungeon Magazine 117, pg. 78) and already have Dodge, Mobility, and Spring Attack as core feat (very expensive) or through magical items that grant those feats (if you 'd rather spend gold than expending your precious feats), you can get an additional +2 Dex bonus that will stack over the one granted by a _Manual of Quickness_ because it is an untyped ability bonus and not an inherent one